# linux inotify - determine users for the triggered events

Tags: monitoring, linux-kernel, inotify

I am trying to figure out how to determine the user which triggered a specific event when monitoring some files with inotify. Is that even possible? Does the inotify_event structure has something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inotify_event` doesn't have a field for that. Since inotify is asynchronous you can't catch the user in the act either.

Have you considered a fuse filesystem? I think [LoggedFS](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) (GPL2+) fits the bill.